# Laravel .env config DB_HOST 127.0.0.1 or mysql

Tags: laravel-9

After starting a project (Laravel with Docker) according to https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows

There is a problem with *DB_HOST* in .env:
To perform artisan commands like `php artisan migrate:fresh` *DB_HOST* need to be set to *127.0.0.1* or *localhost* which makes sense to me.

But when displaying information on browser (localhost) *DB_HOST* need to be *mysql*, otherwise connection is refused.

Why would *DB_HOST* be set to mysql at all? How could I solve it so *DB_HOST* work for both cases?

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 || localhost || mysql(?)
DB_PORT=3306
B_DATABASE=tutorial
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Database

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to find the docker IP with:

```
dd(Request::ip());
```

That was not 127.0.0.1 but 172.18.0.1.
After that I configured .ENV file with:

```
DB_HOST=172.18.0.1
```

And run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

from docker terminal(and NOT from local) and everything works OK

Unfortunately, I don't know how to explain why, I hope someone else can shed a little more light on the matter